# If I can change or set animation duration for Quasar notify plugin?

Tags: quasar-framework, quasar

Becuase the default animation looks a little slowly in my scenario.

From the official documents, https://quasar.dev/quasar-plugins/notify, I only found `timeout` parameter, and it means

> Amount of time to display (in milliseconds)

That's not what I means, does anybody has similar requirements? Thank you for your any advice.

Comment: I see that is the expected behavior of timeout: the amount of time showing the msg on screen, reduce it to hide it fast

in case your interest is the type of animation not duration I suggest to clarify the question

Answer (score 3):

You can assign your own class to notification in config:

```
config: {
    notify: {
        ...
        classes: 'mynotification',
    },
},
```

and then change transition property in css:

```
.mynotification {
    transition: 0.4s ease all;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The answer by @Emptyfortress is correct. Add a 'myNotification' class:

```
$q.notify({
    timeout: 2000,
    color: 'green-4',
    textColor: 'white',
    icon: 'cloud_done',
    message: 'Submitted',
    classes: 'myNotification'
})

<style>
    .myNotification {
    transition: 0.1s ease all;
}
</style>
```